# Visualize influence of an input in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Is there a way to visualize the influence of an Input image on the output of a net?
I have a VGG net for example, and I use a dog image and get the correct label at the output. I want to be able to see what parts of the input image had the influence that gave correct output that correspond with what the network look for in a dog image.Is there a way to create a influence heat-map?
I tried to work with `tf.gradient` with no success. 
Thanks

Comment: It should be possible to do this using `tf.gradients()`. Can you share a reproducible example of what you tried, and the error you so, so maybe someone will be able to help you out?